# If $|f(x)|\leq |g(x)|$, then is it true that $|\int_a^b f(x)|\leq|\int_a^b g(x)|?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

If $|f(x)|\leq |g(x)|$ then $|\int_a^b f(x)| \leq |\int_a^b g(x)|$.

I know that by Triangle inequality,
$$\left|\int_a^b f(x)\right|\leq\int_a^b\left|f(x)\right|$$
and that
$$\left|\int_a^b g(x)\right|\leq\int_a^b\left|g(x)\right|$$
It's true that $\int_a^b\left|f(x)\right|\leq\int_a^b\left|g(x)\right|$, right? But is it necessarily true that
$$\left|\int_a^b f(x)\right|\leq\left|\int_a^b g(x)\right|?$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not,

take $f(x) = |x|$, $g(x) = x$ and a non-zero $a=-b$

Comment: I see. I assume that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are always positive then it would be true, right?

Comment: yes, consider that in general it is true that $f(x) \leq g(x) \implies \int_a^b f(x) \leq \int_a^b g(x)$, which is a really useful property to prove theorems

Answer (score 1):

What about $a=-1$ and $b=1$, $g(x)=-2$, $f(x)=-1$ for $x \in [-1,0)$ and $g(x)=f(x)=2$ for $x \in [0,1]$?